# Remove match elements from list using Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write a function which takes in two lists, L1 and L2, and returns a list which contains all of L1 except for the elements which are also found in L2.
Example: Pass in `'(1 2 3)` `'(3 4 5)` and the return should be `'(1 2)`
I have written a helper function called `removeOne` which is working perfectly fine:

```
(define (removeOne x L)
   (cond ((null? L) '())
   ((= (car L) x) (removeOne x (cdr L)))
   (#t (cons (car L) (removeOne x (cdr L))))))
```

My issue is with the main function which is supposed to use `removeOne` to get rid of all matching elements from L1. I have written this so far:

```
(define (removeAll L1 L2)
    (cond ((null? L1) '()) 
    ((null? L2) '())
    ((= (car L1) (car L2)) (removeOne (car L2) L1))
    (#t (removeAll (cdr L1) L2))))
```

This is currently returning `()` no matter what lists I use as input.
I feel like I'm close to getting this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `(#t ...` This is scheme, not common lisp. We have `else` for a trailing catch-call clause in `cond`.

Answer (score 1):

I have hard time following your logic in `removeAll`. Since you have written a `removeOne`, shouldn't you just call `removeOne` with all elements of `L2`?

Besides, this condition

```lisp
    ((null? L2) '())
```

is strange.

You are supposed to return all elements of L1 that are not in L2. And L2 is empty. So, all elements of L1 that are not in `'()`... how can this be the empty list? No elements are in `()`. So, "all elements of L1 that are not in `()`" is just a convoluted way to say "`L1`". So, clearly, case `(null? L2)` should be associated to result `L1`.

So, if I summarize the recursion of `removeAll`, what you want to do is remove `(car L2)` from L1, then remove all of `(cdr L2)` from that result (or the other way, it doesn't really matter). Unless `L2` is empty, in which case, `removeAll` has nothing to remove.

So

```lisp
(define (removeAll L1 L2)
    (if (null? L2) 
        L1
        (removeAll (removeOne (car L2) L1) (cdr L2))))
```

Or,

```lisp
(define (removeAll L1 L2)
    (if (null? L2)
        L1
        (removeOne (car L2) (removeAll L1 (cdr L2)))))
```

(same result. The 1st one remove first `(car L2)` from `L1`, then remove `(cdr L2)` from the result. The second one remove first `(cdr L2)` from `L1`, then remove `(car L2)` from the result. In other words, the 1st one remove one by one elements of L2 from L1, in the normal order, while the second one does it in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few atomic functions for [searchcing lists, like `member`](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-ref.html#Searching-Lists), that you can use.  Using such a function you will reduce your problem to a recursive function with 3 cases: null, match and otherwise.  Depending on your interest to compare objects, you will use `member` or other one, they use all a different equality operator.